# If $a\geq 2$, $a\nmid b$, and $a^n-1\mid b^n-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $b=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $a\geq 2$, $a\nmid b$, and  $a^n-1\mid b^n-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $b=1$.

PS: In fact, if we do not assume that $a\nmid b$, then the statement should be $b=a^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. The above statement can deduce the fact.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

[image: This is a solution here which was found in some paper in AMM. it's a very nice proof. but it's very constructive. For example, the construction of $Q_k(x)$, $p_k$ and $r_{k,n}$, it's not so easy to construct them. Maybe there is some direct method.]

This is a solution here which was found in some paper in AMM. it's a very nice proof. but it's very constructive. For example, the construction of $Q_k(x)$, $p_k$ and $r_{k,n}$, it's not so easy to construct them. Maybe there is some direct method.

Answer (score 1):

For another proof we can apply this [fact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324115/the-product-of-fracbi-abi-1-lies-in-a-special-ring-conjecture) with the additional information that the $deg_{t_{n+1}} F$ can be chosen to be equal to $n$.

More precisely, from the fact that $\frac{a^n-1}{b^n-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ for every $n$ we get that $\frac{(ab)^n-1}{b^n-1}\in\mathbb{Z}$ for every $n$. So from the [fact](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324115/the-product-of-fracbi-abi-1-lies-in-a-special-ring-conjecture) applied to $ab, b$ and the information that $deg_{t_{n+1}} F\leq n$ we get that $\frac{2^n(b-ab)(b^2-ab)\dots(b^n-ab)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\dots(b^n-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{2^n(1-a)(b-a)\dots(b^{n-1}-a)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\dots(b^n-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$ (here we used $gcd(b, b^i-1)=1$). But if $b>2$ we get obvious $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n(1-a)(b-a)\dots(b^{n-1}-a)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\dots(b^n-1)}=0$ and $a=b^k$ for some $k$. In the case $b=2$ we conclude that even $\frac{(b-a)(b^2-a)\dots(b^n-a)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\dots(b^n-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and from $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1-a)(b-a)\dots(b^{n-1}-a)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\dots(b^n-1)}=0$ we have $a=b^k$ for some $k$. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proof from [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h203167).

$\textbf{Problem 1.}$ Prove that if $b^n-1\mid a^n-1$  for all $n$, then $a=b^k$ for some integer $k$.

$\textbf{Lemma 1.}$ If $b^n-1\mid a^n-1$  for all $n$, then $(b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^n-1)\mid n!(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{n-1})$ for every $n$.

$\textbf{Proof of Lemma 1.}$ First consider any prime $p\mid (b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^n-1)$, so there exists minimal $d$ such that $p\mid b^d-1$ and it's well-known fact that then $x^d-1\equiv (x-1)(x-b)\ldots (x-b^{d-1})\pmod{p^{\nu_p(b^d-1)}}$, so $P(x)=x^d-1$ has exactly $d$ consecutive roots $1, b, b^2,\ldots , b^{d-1}$. From the condition $b^d-1\mid a^d-1$ we get that $a$ is also the root of polynomial $x^d-1$. So easy to see that there exists only one $0\leq d'\leq d$, such that $a-b^{d'}\equiv 0\pmod{p^{\nu_p(b^d-1)}}$. From this we get that for all $i\equiv d'\pmod{d}$, $a-b^i\equiv 0\pmod{p^{\nu_p(b^d-1)}}$. Now from LTE lemma we get that $\nu_p(b^{jd}-1)\leq\nu_p(b^d-1)+\nu_p(j)$, for each $j$, so $\nu_p(\prod_{i=1}^n(b^i-1))\leq[n/d]\nu_p(b^d-1)+\nu_p(n!)\leq\nu_p(n!(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{n-1}))$. Combining similar inequalities for every $p$ we get Lemma 1. $\Box$

$\textbf{Proof of Problem 1.}$ Firstly it's simple exercise to prove that if a prime $p$ is such that $p\mid a$, then $p\mid b$. So there exists a positive integer $t$, such that $a\nmid b^{t-1}$, but $a\mid b^t$. From Lemma 1 we get that $(2t)!\frac{(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{t-1})(a-b^t)\ldots (a-b^{2t-1})}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^t-1)(b^{t+1}-1)\ldots (b^{2t}-1)}\in\mathbb{Z}$. But for every $i$ we have that $\gcd(a, b^i-1)$, so if we just look on the numerator of the fraction above then we get that $$\gcd(a,1)\gcd(a, b)\ldots gcd(a, b^{t-1})a^t\mid (2t)!\frac{(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{t-1})(a-b^t)\ldots (a-b^{2t-1})}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^t-1)(b^{t+1}-1)\ldots (b^{2t}-1)}$$ and if $a\not= b^x$  for every natural $x$, then $$|(2t)!\frac{(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{t-1})(a-b^t)\ldots (a-b^{2t-1})}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^t-1)(b^{t+1}-1)\ldots (b^{2t}-1)}|\geq gcd(a,1)\gcd(a, b)\ldots gcd(a, b^{t-1})a^t$$ But it's easy to check that $|(2t)!\frac{(a-1)(a-b)\ldots (a-b^{t-1})(a-b^t)\ldots (a-b^{2t-1})}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\ldots (b^t-1)(b^{t+1}-1)\ldots (b^{2t}-1)}|\leq (2t)!a^t$ and $gcd(a,1)\gcd(a, b)\ldots gcd(a, b^{t-1})\geq 2^{\frac{t(t-1)}{2}}$ (here we used the fact that $\gcd(a, b^i)\mid\gcd(a, b^{i+1})$ and $\gcd(a, b^{i-1})\not=\gcd(a, b^i)$ for $i\leq t-1$). So $2^{\frac{t(t-1)}{2}}a^t\leq (2t)!a^t$. Contradiction. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Reference for a generalization of this theorem and it's proof in French. See this [article](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_044_2015/183_44.pdf).

*Langlois, Bruno*, An arithmetical application of Hadamard’s quotient theorem, Ann. Univ. Sci. Budap. Rolando Eötvös, Sect. Comput. 44, 183-196 (2015). [ZBL1389.11046](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1389.11046).