# Constraints on equations $(a^n-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

When I first read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125907/conjecture-about-the-system-of-powerful-equations) (Conjecture about the system of powerful equations) about systems of equations where $(a^n-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$, I assumed the question indicated the modular relationship was to be true for every $n\in \mathbb N$. Reading the comments, however, it became clear that the question was about systems where the modular relationships are true for all $n\le m$.

If $(a^n-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$ for all $n$, $a=b^k$ is one possibility, as that would result in $((b^n)^k-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$ which is true for all $n$. However, for the narrower case where $n\le m$ (in particular $m=2$, so $n=1,2$), an example was given where $(a^n-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$, but $a\ne b^k$ ($a=5,\ b=3$).

This raises two related questions:

**1.** In the case where $n$ has no upper limit, are there solutions to the system of equations $\forall n: (a^n-1)\equiv 0 \mod (b^n-1)$ other than $a=b^k$?

**2.** If not, then is there a value of $m$ above which there are no other solutions than $a=b^k$?

Answer (score 1):

Reference for part $1$ see [here (the first answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964788/if-a-geq-2-a-nmid-b-and-an-1-mid-bn-1-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-then/3061000#3061000). From my proof ([the second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964788/if-a-geq-2-a-nmid-b-and-an-1-mid-bn-1-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-then/3061000#3061000)) we get that it's enough to assume that $m = a$ and it gives some answer for the part $2$. In fact the same proof allows us to formulate the next motivational theorem (this theorem can be seen as a motivation to the [Conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125907/conjecture-about-the-system-of-powerful-equations)).

> $\bf{Theorem.}$
>
> Let given a system of modular equations
>
> $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a-1 \equiv 0\mod{b-1}\\a^2-1 \equiv 0\mod{b^2-1}\\ \ldots\\a^n-1 \equiv 0\mod{b^n-1}\end{array}\right. (\star)$$
>
> Then $\frac{(b-a)(b^2-a)\cdot\ldots\cdot(b^n-a)}{(b-1)(b^2-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(b^n-1)} = \frac{u}{v}$, where $v$ the divisor of $n!$.