# If $x,y\geq 2$ and $\forall n, x^n-1\mid y^n-1,$ show $y$ is a power of $x.$

Tags: number-theory

While studying mathematics, I was able to think of the following because $x^{nk}-1$ is a multiple of $x^n-1$ for every natural number $n$. ($x,k$ are natural numbers)

If $x,y \geq 2$ are integers and $y^n-1$ is a multiple of $x^n-1$ for every natural number $n$, than $y$ is power of $x$

I asked this question on the math question board used at school, and was recommended to read the following paper.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00209-002-0449-z.pdf

However, in this paper, there is no proof of this problem, using expressions such as 'It is a known amusing elementary problem to prove that' or 'This is a particular case of the so-called Hadamard Quotient theorem'.

I tried to look up the references for this article, but I couldn't find a link. How can I prove this?

Comment: $x^{k} - 1 = (x-1)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} + \cdots + x + 1)\implies 
x^{nk} - 1 = (x^n-1)(x^{n(k-1)} + x^{n(k-2)} + \cdots + x^n + 1)$

Comment: If there is a counterexample, there is an example with $y\neq1$ not a multiple of $x.$ This is because $$(xq)^n-1\equiv q^n-1\pmod{x^n-1},$$ so if $y=xq$ satisfies your condition, then $y=q$ works.

Comment: See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h203167p1117929), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h4556p14248) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964788/if-a-geq-2-a-nmid-b-and-an-1-mid-bn-1-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-then?noredirect=1)